# Why isn't powershell loading the SQLPS module correctly

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm loading SQLPS by using

```
Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking
```

on a windows server 2008 R2 box.

It gives me the error

> The assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.HadrDMF' was not loaded
>   because no assembly was found

Google-fu is failing me... help me hivemind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that in addition to the PowerShell Extensions you also install the Shared Management Objects which in turn requires the System CLR Types. These all are found in:

[MS SQL Server 2012 Features Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)